# From 7 inputs and 1 output, approximate a possible function?

Tags: functions, interpolation, data-analysis

I'm trying to approximate a car insurance quote algorithm/function:

It takes 7 input variables that I can change (Vehicle Cost, Post Code, Gender, Persons Age, Licence type, Licence age, and excess) and outputs a single numerical solution (Cost/week). I've already created a web scraper to collect data for me for one provider.

I'm looking for some direction on the possibilities of this; where to start; topics are relevant. Its a really interesting scenario that I can learn alot from

Eg n(0): 
Vehicle cost = $10,000 
Post Code = 1025 
Gender = M 
Age [Person] = 30 
Licence Type = Full 
Licence age = 10

Output = $45 / week

Function approximation = ???

Thank you

Comment: Does the output depend on **all** the parameters you mentioned?

Comment: Hi Sai yes it definitely does I've manually toggled inputs (there are more than what I've provided) but these 7 are the only ones that have an affect the output. Cheers

Comment: @sai-kartik ^as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bunch of data, not just one point.  Several of the inputs are discrete, not continuous-sex, license type, post code.  The others are continuous.  The simplest assumption is that the cost is a linear function of each of the continuous variables and the functions are either added or multiplied.  You can change each of the variables to find the linear function it creates and see if it is linear.  Then you can change two of them and try to see how they are combined.  The sex and license type don't have many options.  The simplest is a fixed difference depending on the response.  The post code may well impact the constants in the effects of the continuous variables.

It is research.  Collect data, make a theory that explains it, and collect some more data to test the theory.

Comment: Thanks @Ross, My approach going forward Is to constrain most variables and see whether cost is linear. From there I’ll constrain everything except postcode: and create a quote for all 1800 postcodes. I then want to find the min and max postcodes and normalise all postcodes within this min max range with a weighting against the quote - cheers